# Java SendHttpPost is bringing back null JSONObject

Tags: java, android, json, http-post

I have sorted through almost every JSON httppost tutorial and question on StackOverflow, and think I may be going crazy. At one point, my Android app was flawlessly pulling down data and displaying it after submitting a JSONObject and receiving a JSONObject. Now, after losing a day's worth of coding, I cannot get it to work again.

I used [this](https://github.com/znq/Simple-HTTP-Client/blob/master/src/com/devstream/http/HttpClient.java) as a basis the first time and it worked then, so can someone please tell me why I might be getting null errors in the HttpClient.java?

UPDATE: Seems to be working now, kinda. But the received JSON is supposed to look something like [this](http://pastebin.com/4mWQvdss), and instead all it contains is {"mainSearchResult":[]}. Thoughts?

Note: Yes, I do have all of my imports, and the LogCat can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/ygWcizWs). I have only been programming with Java and Android for about 3 weeks so please explain clearly and as simply as possible, hopefully without relying on other StackOverflow posts to explain it because I assure you, I have already read it.

```
public class HttpClient {

public static final String TAG = HttpClient.class.getSimpleName();

public static JSONObject SendHttpPost(String URL, JSONObject jsonObjSend) {

    try {
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPostRequest = new HttpPost(URL);

        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(jsonObjSend.toString());

        // Set HTTP parameters
        httpPostRequest.setEntity(se);
        httpPostRequest.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPostRequest.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
        HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpPostRequest);
        Log.i(TAG, "HTTPResponse received in [" + (System.currentTimeMillis()-t) + "ms]");

        // Get hold of the response entity (-> the data):
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        if (entity != null) {
            // Read the content stream
            InputStream instream = entity.getContent();

            // convert content stream to a String
            String resultString= convertStreamToString(instream);
            instream.close();

            // Transform the String into a JSONObject
            JSONObject jsonObjRecv = new JSONObject(resultString);
            // Raw DEBUG output of our received JSON object:
            Log.i(TAG,"<JSONObject>\n"+jsonObjRecv.toString()+"\n</JSONObject>");

            return jsonObjRecv;
        } 

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // More about HTTP exception handling in another tutorial.
        // For now we just print the stack trace.
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}


private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    /*
     * To convert the InputStream to String we use the BufferedReader.readLine()
     * method. We iterate until the BufferedReader return null which means
     * there's no more data to read. Each line will appended to a StringBuilder
     * and returned as String.
     * 
     * (c) public domain: http://senior.ceng.metu.edu.tr/2009/praeda/2009/01/11/a-simple-restful-client-at-android/
     */
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

}

Comment: Looks like your resultString isnt a valid json object, try printing out your resultString or debugging your application to see what its value is. You may also consider taking your resultString variable outside your try catch and if you encounter an error you can print it out. Also add in a JSONException in your try catch so you can narrow your execption types for debugging.

Comment: Updated with additional information

Comment: I couldnt tell you, It has something to do with where your retrieving the data from, what parameters your passing it ect... I would say figure out what the http call is and test it in a browser, see if you can get the results from there and work at it from that angle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use different convertStreamToString method:

```
 private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        /*
         * To convert the InputStream to String we use the BufferedReader.readLine()
         * method. We iterate until the BufferedReader return null which means
         * there's no more data to read. Each line will appended to a StringBuilder
         * and returned as String.
         */
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

After this try to print the response (This is in your "Try Catch" scope):

```
String result= convertStreamToString(instream);
// now you have the string representation of the HTML request
instream.close();
Log.d("Reponse from request:",result); //Where you print to LogChat theresponse
```

And then I whould try to parsethe String to JSONObject

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);             
   if(result!=null)
   {
    //Here is where you do your thing....
   }
```

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, that convertStreamToString method is exactly what I used, character for character. Also, I have logged the result from the convertSTreamToString and when doing so, still get String of {"mainSearchResult":[]}

Comment: Yes I saw it now..Sorry
Can it be that the response is empty? can you show the JSON you are trying to parse?

Comment: To see the JSON data that I am trying to pull down, and how it should appear, see the Update in the original post. And apparently they had some server issues, but now instead of actual json data, I am receiving the actual HTML that makes up the error page saying that the file could not be found (on their server).

Answer (score 0):

```
May this help you.

 // Creating JSON Parser instance
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
        JsonArray jsonArray=json.getJSONArray("mainSearchResult");
String strAudio=jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getString("AudioStr");//move the loop towards it upto jsonArray.length() and get all the string in the same manner

  public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
```